# Django remove foreign relationship from model

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models. I want to remove the `recommendation` foreign field from the `Document` model and change it to `many-to-many.`

```
class Recommendation(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    recommendation = models.ForeignKey(Recommendation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Inteded result:

```
class Recommendation(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    documents = models.ManyToManyField('Document')


class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
```

But there is an error when I run `./manage.py makemigrations` 
 `<class 'questions.admin.DocumentInline'>: (admin.E202) 'questions.Document' has no ForeignKey to 'questions.Recommendation'.`

Comment: Check your `admin.py` files (in the app questions), the error points there. Likely you have forgotten to change them to reflect the change you made to the models.

Comment: Great, thank you. It worked. If you answer I will accept

Comment: I don't know if this can be considered an answer, I just reminded you of what the error meant and pointed you to check there. Just enjoy your problem being solved. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Abdul Aziz Barkat Answered this question in the comments but didn't want to write an answer.
 The problem was in `admin.py` where `Document` model inlined in `Recommendation` model

```
class DocumentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    extra = 1
    model = Document


@admin.register(Recommendation)
class Recommendation_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DocumentInline]
```